# Is there a way to override the init script template in sbt-native-packager?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

Using sbt-native-packager `1.0.0`

sbt-native-packager uses [this init script template](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/0a6be58f7402c5ef44d7d1d84c83076ffe2e191a/src/main/resources/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/archetypes/systemloader/systemv/start-rpm-template) to create a startup script (in `/etc/init.d/<package-name>`) when building an rpm. I would like to override this init script with one of my own, but I can't seem to locate the best way to do this. It's very possible that I'm just overlooking something (I am new to Scala, and perusing the source is a little difficult), so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I just want the contents of the init script installed with the rpm to be taken from a file that I specify in the build.sbt file. Any help is greatly appreciated (the more detail you provide, the better).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your init script to `scr/templates/systemloader/systemv`.
Take a look to http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/systemloaders.html#override-start-script for more details.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I created a file called `src/templates/rpm/systemv`, and placed the words "hello world" inside of this file, but the default init script still gets installed. I found a [debian example](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/tree/94e918e2bca8d739421e7cefe64b57fe75068204/src/sbt-test/debian/override-start-script/src/templates/systemloader) that places the overriding template in `src/templates/systemloader` so I tried that too. Neither solution works :(  Is there anything else I could be missing? i.e. do I need to specify any in build.sbt?

Comment: [This line](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/e4e6504c1f6a75fb346958f68d0f7c13fec26877/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/archetypes/systemloader/package.scala#L74) in the sbt-native-packager code also supports my comment above, about templates being loaded from `src/templates/systemloader`. Unfortunately, I still haven't gotten it to work. I'll keep digging, but if you have any suggestions, please let me know

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/pull/891
As a workaround you could use `src/main/templates/systemloader/systemv` until this PR will be merged.

Comment: The `1.2.0-M6` release includes the fix.